# Export to JSON format

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have the following 2 tables. Actually I need to sync all table related and non related table to another database. Am using SQL Server 2017.

---

```
 CREATE TABLE EmailAddresses (
        ID int,
        EmailAddress varchar(255),
         StartDate datetime,
        EndDate datetime,   
    );   

 CREATE TABLE Cards (
        ID int,
        CardNumber varchar(255),
        ValidFrom datetime, 
        ValidTo datetime,  
        CVC  varchar(255),   
    );
```

I need all the records of 2 table in single json file ( format is as below) .

```
{ 
    "Sync By" : "XYZ", 
    "Sync Date" : "2021-10-16",
    "EmailAddresses" : [
        {
            "EmailAddress" : "Aisha@AEL.com", 
            "StartDate" : "2015-11-12", 
            "EndDate" : "2019-06-21"
        }, 
        {
            "EmailAddress" : "Elsie@Livulook.co.wm", 
            "StartDate" : "2014-02-09", 
            "EndDate" : "2015-12-23"
        }, 
        {
            "EmailAddress" : "Harriet23@Zaha.com", 
            "StartDate" : "2013-07-26", 
            "EndDate" : "2018-04-16"
        }
    ], 
    "Cards" : [
        {
            "CardNumber" : "340365242116610", 
            "ValidFrom" : "2015-07-28", 
            "ValidTo" : "2021-10-16", 
            "CVC" : "205"
        }

    ]
}
```

Comment: Where do you think `StartDate` could be taken from? You have it in json but not in SQL?

Comment: data taken from tables rows ex: EmailAddress table

Comment: that's the whole point - `StartDate` is in not the table you specified

Comment: sory updated the table design .,added start date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve that with the `for json`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-query-results-as-json-with-for-json-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

These two will produce two json arrays which if combined together will give you the desired format.

These two properties:
`Sync By` and `Sync Date` do not exist in database hence they need to be adjusted manually at the export time.

```
 select 'XYZ' as 'Sync By',
 select '2021-10-16' as 'Sync Date',

 (select ID, EmailAddress, StartDate, EndDate,   
         from table EmailAddresses
         for json path) EmailAddresses,

 (select Id, CardNumber, ValidFrom, ValidTo, CVC
         from table Cards
         for json path) Cards

  for json path
```

Comment: copy and paste these two json arrays one after another - that's the simplest way. Your are still missing the information sources for two json properties, so manual step is required anyway. Once you get all sources you can script it with stored procedures.

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach is to export the data from the two tables using `FOR JSON AUTO` and then generate the final output using `FOR JSON PATH` with `WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER` option:

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE EmailAddresses (
        ID int,
        EmailAddress varchar(255),
        StartDate datetime,
        EndDate datetime,   
    );   

CREATE TABLE Cards (
        ID int,
        CardNumber varchar(255),
        ValidFrom datetime, 
        ValidTo datetime,  
        CVC  varchar(255),   
);
INSERT INTO EmailAddresses
   (ID, EmailAddress, StartDate, EndDate)
VALUES
   (1, 'Aish"a@AEL.com', '2015-11-12', '2019-06-21'),
   (2, 'Aisha@AEL.com', '2015-11-12', '2019-06-21'),
   (3, 'Aisha@AEL.com', '2015-11-12', '2019-06-21')
INSERT INTO Cards 
   (ID, CardNumber, ValidFrom, ValidTo, CVC)
VALUES
   (1, '340365242116610', '2015-07-28', '2021-10-16', '205')
```

Statement:

```
SELECT 
   [Sync By] = 'XYZ', 
   [Sync Date] = '2021-10-16',
   [EmailAddresses] = (
      SELECT EmailAddress, StartDate, EndDate  
      FROM EmailAddresses
      FOR JSON AUTO
   ),
   [Cards] = (
       SELECT CardNumber, ValidFrom, ValidTo, CVC
       FROM Cards
       FOR JSON AUTO
   )
FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
```